# Property of Dirac operator in spinor frame bundle

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, dirac-equation, dirac-matrices

The Dirac operator is defined by
$$d=g(e_\alpha,e_\beta) \gamma(e_\beta)\nabla_{e_\alpha} \tag1$$
Here $\nabla$ is the spin covariante derivative $e_\alpha$ basis of the tangent space and $\gamma$ the Dirac matrix.
If $A$ is an element of the orthogonal group $SO(1,3)$ under change of basis of the for $e_\mu=A_\nu^{\mu}e_\mu$
the Dirac operator transform  as

$$D=g(e_\alpha,e_\beta) A_\beta^\sigma\gamma(e_\sigma)\nabla_{A_\alpha^\eta e_\eta} =(A^T)_\alpha^\eta g(e_\alpha,e_\beta) A_\beta^\sigma\gamma(e_\sigma)\nabla_{ e_\eta}\tag2=d$$
Where I used the fact that $A^TgA=g$

Now spinors $\psi$  are $g$ equivariant functions on  the spinor bundle that is
$\psi(g\cdot p)=g^{-1}\cdot \psi(p)$ for $g\in SL(2,C)$.

Now by the structure of spin frame bundle,  changing  basis in the frame bundle induces a transformation in the spin frame bundle so if $\phi(p)$ is the spin given by
$$\phi(p)=D\psi(p)$$ under a change of basis we should have
$$\phi(g\cdot p)=g^{-1}\cdot\phi(\cdot p)= g^{-1}D\psi(p) \tag 3$$
If g is a constant that  we have that $D\psi(gp)=Dg^{-1}\psi(p)=g^{-1}D\psi(p)=g^{-1}D\psi(p)$

My question is this how to show that $(3)$ is satisfied for group element $g(p)$ that is not constant ?

Comment: Are you just copying out material? This isn't how one learns physics ...

Comment: The orthogonal group is usually notated SO(1,3) ...

Comment: "The structure of the spin frame bundle changing basis", besides being grammatically incorrect, also is incorrect in terms of the terminology ...